# Google App Engine and Service Accounts

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

I went went trough the service accounts for accessing api's of Google.

Initially there is no option for appengine to use service accounts. 
No I found this URL which says we can do the same.
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/platforms/google_app_engine#ServiceAccounts

I tried out the process couldn't achieve success. On the other part i have two questions.

1. How this api identifies whats the Google Project Account I have billing in.
2. The process no where uses the private the key we got from Google Console. 

   <strike>And when i tried out this is what i see.</strike>

   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/base/data/home/apps/tempid/cons-main.361607602228494295/main.py", line 63, in 
       service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)
     File "/base/data/home/apps/tempid/cons-main.361607602228494295/oauth2client/util.py", line 120, in positional_wrapper
       return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
     File "/base/data/home/apps/tempid/cons-main.361607602228494295/apiclient/discovery.py", line 193, in build
       resp, content = http.request(requested_url)
     File "/base/data/home/apps/tempid/cons-main.361607602228494295/oauth2client/util.py", line 120, in positional_wrapper
       return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
     File "/base/data/home/apps/tempid/cons-main.361607602228494295/oauth2client/client.py", line 405, in new_request
       self._refresh(request_orig)
     File "/base/data/home/apps/tempid/cons-main.361607602228494295/oauth2client/appengine.py", line 162, in _refresh
       raise AccessTokenRefreshError(str(e))
   AccessTokenRefreshError
   .

Any answers?
Pls ignore the error above, i got this sorted out. the error was in defining the scope.

I added my appengine apps service account ID to console, Added billing & am not using any API key.

```
 service.files().insert(
        body=body,
        ).execute()
```

This statement throws an exception.

```
An error occured: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?alt=json returned "Daily Limit Exceeded. Please sign up">
```

I wonder if i have added my appengine service account to 2-3 projects at api console and i am not using any api key where will the data from this project get into. –

Comment: It's not very clear what exactly you're asking here.. Did you actually went through the documentation and tried some fully functional examples? From the link that you provided they have examples that demonstrate exactly that in a full application. Did that work?

Comment: this error posted is from the functional example provided by api team for service accounts..http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/#hg%2Fsamples%2Fstorage_serviceaccount_appengine  it didnt work so I posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service accounts are only supported with some particular services.  It appears you're trying to use the Google Drive SDK, so I added google-drive-sdk tag.  Hopefully someone watching that tag can tell you whether Drive supports service accounts.

Provided service accounts are supported with Drive -- please update the post with your exact code.  Are you using the correct [Google Drive scope](https://developers.google.com/drive/scopes#google_drive_scopes) when instatiating the `AppAssertionCredentials` object?

You may wish to try this in the [App Engine shell](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api) first so you can catch the exceptions easily and check what's inside the exception object.  You'll hopefully be able to find the error response returned by the server when trying to get an access token.

You may have to add the App Engine service account e-mail address (from the App Engine console) as a team member on the API Console project.  We have to do this to link up for billing/data permissions on BigQuery.

You will not have to use any private key from the APIs console -- App Engine handles the service account creation and key management automatically.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I got this sorted, I am able to build connection for Google Drive SDK. I am now trying with providing api key and without providing api key. We are using api console via Google Apps Account(Not Gmail), where we are not able to add users to team from different domain. So i was not able to add service account from appengine to my api console where i have billing enabled :(, If i try account without billing, it says quota error. If i use api key `Authentication token must be issued to a non-anonymous app.` this is the error showing up.

Comment: I wonder if i have added my appengine service account to 2-3 projects at api console and i am not using any api key where will the data from this project get into.

Comment: Data is actually stored based on the user account.  In this case, the App Engine service account is actually a user account (with the e-mail address specified).  You can't login via the UI, but data is stored in the same manner.  So the biggest question isn't how the data is stored, but what application (from the APIs console) it's associated with.  The "different domain" error is frustrating- I know.

Comment: Billing be enabled in APIs console or not shouldn't affect this testing.  However, you would need to have the Google Drive service enabled, or you'd get quota errors.

Comment: I removed service account added to different projects in different accounts(gmail and apps). Added it to one api console of gmail account. Enabled drive SDK & API and enabled billing. An error occured: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?alt=json returned "Daily Limit Exceeded. Please sign up">